# Chrome extension to change dropdown value

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension that changes the default country value in a dropdown once the page loads.

This is what the HTML page look like (using the inspect button):

```
<select _ngcontent-jfu-c2="" aria-label="Select Geography" class="input__select input__select--big select-drop ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" name="geographies">
<!---->
<option _ngcontent-jfu-c2="" value="40: Object"> Canada </option>
<option _ngcontent-jfu-c2="" value="240: Object"> United States </option>
</select>
```

I want it to change from whatever selection to 'Canada'. This is my extension:

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Default Country Changer",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://server.com/"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ]
  }
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.url === 'https://server.com') {
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tab.id },
        files: ['content.js']
      });
    }
  });
```

content.js

```
let dropdown = document.getElementById('_ngcontent-wsg-c2');
if (dropdown) {
  dropdown.value = 'Canada';
}
```

It is not working at all. Any suggestions? Thank you in advanced!

Create a simple Chrome extension that changes the default country value in a dropdown.